# Error: Unexpected value 'DropdownMultiselectModule' with Angular2

Tags: angular, webpack

I got that error while trying to import this module : https://github.com/AndyMeps/ng2-dropdown-multiselect

I think it's because of my webpack configuration, here it is :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const StringReplacePlugin = require('string-replace-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (options) {
const DATAS = {
    VERSION: JSON.stringify(require("../package.json").version),
    DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: options.env === 'dev'
};
return {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
        'global': './src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css',
        'vendor': [
            './src/main/webapp/app/vendor',
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/forms',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/upgrade',
            '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap',
            'angular2-cookie',
            'jquery',
            'ng-jhipster',
            'ng2-webstorage',
            'rxjs',
            'ui-router-ng2'
        ],
        'main': './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: ['node_modules']
    },
    output: {
        path: './target/www',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        proxy: [{
            context: [
                '/api',
                '/management',
                '/swagger-resources',
                '/v2/api-docs',
                '/h2-console'
            ],
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
            secure: false
        }]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /[\/]angular\.js$/, loader: "exports-loader?angular" },
            { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery' },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    'angular2-template-loader',
                    'awesome-typescript-loader'
                ],
                exclude: ['node_modules/generator-jhipster']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader',
                exclude: ['./src/main/webapp/index.html']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
                exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|mp4)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                    'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /app.constants.ts$/,
                loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
                    replacements: [{
                        pattern: /\/\* @toreplace (\w*?) \*\//ig,
                        replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
                            return `_${p1} = ${DATAS[p1]};`;
                        }
                    }
                ]})
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ['manifest', 'polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist', to: 'swagger-ui/dist' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/', to: 'swagger-ui' },
            { from: './src/main/webapp/i18n', to: 'i18n' }
        ]),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/main/webapp/index.ejs',
            chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
            inject: 'body',
            data: DATAS
        }),
        new StringReplacePlugin()
    ]
};
};
```

Here is the complete error message I get :

> "Unexpected value 'DropdownMultiselectModule' imported by the module 'MyAppModule'"

But this is the only module which gives me this error when I try to import it, other modules are working fine.

I'm using **Jhipster 3.12.2**, **Webpack 2.2.0-rc.3**, **Node v6.9.2** and **NPM 3.10.9**

I found this : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11438, but I don't really understand where does my issue come from ?

Answer (score 0):

Moved to this Module : https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect
And everything is now working fine !